determinant of $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & x^T \\ x & C \end{pmatrix}$, where $x$ is n-dimensional column vector and C is $n \times n$ dimensional matrix
I'm trying to find the determinant of
$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & x^T \\
x & C
\end{pmatrix}
$, where $x$ is an n-dimensional column vector and C is an $n \times n$ dimensional square and invertible matrix.
This popped up when trying to reverse engineer a matrix whose determinant is a given quadratic form.
An obvious thing is to consider minors and cofactors. But can't make progress when attempting that.
Any suggestions?

To compute the determinant, we use the known block matrix determinant formula for a matrix $M$ of the following form
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The formula, where $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are matrices, and $D$ is invertible, is given as
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix} = \det(D) \cdot \det(A - BD^{-1}C)
$$
In your case, $A = 0$, $B = x^T$, $C = x$, $D = C$, so, applying the formula gives
$$
\det(A) = \det(C) \cdot \det(0 - x^T C^{-1} x)
$$
Since $x^T C^{-1} x$ is a scalar, the expression simplifies to
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
0 & x^T \\
x & C
\end{pmatrix} = -\det(C) \cdot x^T C^{-1} x
$$
Thus, the determinant is
$$
\det(A) = -x^T C^{-1} x \cdot \det(C)
$$
